# How to pass a variable from back-end (Cold Fusion page) to the front-end (HTML part inside CFM) using jQuery Ajax?

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, cfml

I have a cfm file that has the logic to extract a PDF and convert it into the image file. Now I need to pass the file path of this converted image file to the front-end CFM and set it as a source to the following image tag.

```
<img id="image1" name="importantImage" src="" />
```

I heard about Ajax get() method, but I am not sure, how to make it possible in jQuery? Could someone help me on this?

Sorry, if my question is unclear. Please feel free to ask about the specifics, for a more elaborate explanation.

Comment: Call the script (or CFC) via [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). Have the script/CFC return a JSON string containing the web accessible file path. On "success", extract the path from the JSON and update the img src. Right now this question is really [too broad](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) and may be closed. If you are new to jQuery, start with some *small*, hard coded examples of calling a page via ajax() and go from there.

Comment: Thanks Leigh.. I think I should work on small examples to understand it better..

Comment: Yep. The usual temptation is to try and do everything in one pass... resist it ;-) Start with simple, static examples. Do one piece at a time. Once that piece is working, add in the next piece. If you run into problems with a specific section of code, you can always post back here.

Answer (score 0):

Just save your self the hassle and inject straight into the HTML. If you can move your PDF engine code into a component. You could just put the resulting image url straight into the image;

```
<cfoutput> 
<img id="image1" name="importantImage" src="#MY_IMAGE_URL#" />
</cfoutput>
```

Or you can make it available to javascript by using coldfusion to create the javascript snippet that can then be reference by your main javascript after page load like so:

```
<head>
<script>
    <cfoutput>
    var jsFoo = '#JSStringFormat(MY_IMAGE_URL)#';
    </cfoutput>
</script> 
</head>
```